# What is to define truth in Mathematical Logic?

Tags: logic, formal-languages

Tarski's Undefinability Theorem says that arithmetical truth cannot be defined in arithmetic.

What is the meaning of "definition"? Is it formal?

Comment: In a mathematical proof, no statements are formally classified as "definitions." The term is used for informal discussion purposes only.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is.

According to :

> **TARSKI UNDEFINABILITY THEOREM** (1933) : The set $\# \text {Th} \mathfrak N$ [i.e. the set of Gödel-numbers of sentences true in $\mathfrak N$] is not *definable* in $\mathfrak N$.

Here the concept of *definability* is defined as follows :

> Consider a structure $\mathfrak A$ and a formula $\varphi$ whose free variables are among $v_1,\ldots, v_n$. We can construct the $n$-ary relation on $|\mathfrak A|$
>
> > $\{ \ \langle a_1,\ldots,a_n \rangle \vDash _{\mathfrak A} \varphi [a_1,\ldots, a_n] \ \}$.
>
> Call this the $n$-ary relation $\varphi$ *defines* in $\mathfrak A$.
>
> In general, a $n$-ary relation on $|\mathfrak A|$ is said to be *definable* in $\mathfrak A$ iff there is a formula (whose free variables are among $v_1,\ldots, v_n$) that defines it there.

---

This means that we cannot "manufacture" a formula $\varphi$ in *first-order* language of arithmetic with one free variable such that $\varphi$ holds (in the "standard model" of arithmetic) of exactly those *natural* numbers that are the Gödel numbers of the true sentences of arithmetic.